# Configure Nhibernate 5.3.8 with MySQL8Dialect

Tags: nhibernate, mysql-8.0

I updated NHibernate version and MysqlData version in my c# application

**Version Info**

```
   NHibernate 5.3.8

   MySqlData 8.0.24.0
```

Below my **hibernate_mysql_config.xml**

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory name="hsms.local">
    <property name="connection.driver_class">
      NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver
    </property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">
      data source=xxxxxx;Database=xxxxxx; User ID=xxxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxxx;default command timeout=5000; Convert Zero Datetime=true; Allow Zero Datetime=True;
    </property>
    <property name="adonet.batch_size">
      200
    </property>
    <property name="show_sql">
      false
    </property>
    <property name="connection.isolation">
      ReadCommitted
    </property>
    <property name="dialect">
      NHibernate.Dialect.MySQL8Dialect
    </property>
    <property name="command_timeout">
      60
    </property>
    <property name="query.substitutions">
      true 1, false 0, yes 'Y', no 'N'
    </property>
    <property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
    <property name="cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
    <mapping assembly="Merqurio.Redazione.DL.Model" />
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

When I run my application, I have the following error:

**Could not load type NHibernate.Dialect.MySQL8Dialect. Possible cause: no assembly name specified.":""**

Below the stackTrace:

```
   at NHibernate.Dialect.Dialect.InstantiateDialect(String dialectName, IDictionary 2 props)
   at NHibernate.Dialect.Dialect.GetDialect(IDictionary 2 props)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()
   at Merqurio.Redazione.DAL.Persistance.SessionManagerMySqlDottNet..cctor() in E:\Progetti\Progetti C# Visual Studio\Redazione\trunk\Merqurio.Redazione\Merqurio.Redazione.DAL.Persistence\SessionManagerMySqlDottNet.cs:line 71
```

I've already checked the Dialect spelling. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line in Configuration file

```
 <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
```